# How to fire an element's click function when another element is clicked instead?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Maybe a weird question but I can't figure it out.

Let's say I have a link which, when clicked, does something. Different events are assigned to its click method while the application works. Let's say this link is:

```
<a id="link1">Link 1</a>
```

Now, let's say there's another link, for instance:

```
<a id="link2">Link 2</a>
```

Is there a way, quite simply, to tell Link 2 to fire Link 1's click event/ function?

```
$('#link2').click(function(){
    //find out what Link 1 does when clicked and do the same
});
```

I know there are different ways of getting this to work, such as simply assigning the same events to link1 and link2. I'm more interested from a theoretical standpoint if there's a syntax for what I want to do above.

Comment: what jquery version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"Is there a way, quite simply, to tell Link 2 to do whatever Link 1 does?"*

Yes there is. You may trigger the click event that was bound to the first link with `.click()` or:

```
$('#link2').click(function() {
    $('#link1').trigger('click');
});
```

**UPD:** As initially it was not clear whether you need to preserve the context in the event execution or not, the solution provided above will not perform same actions (*if they are*) with `#link2` element. So in case of event as below, on `#link2` click you'll still get `#link1` red and `#link2` unchanged:

```
$('#link1').click(function() {
    $(this).css('color', '#f00');
});
```

However, if you want to keep context of event in the element you initially clicked and make it aware of `this` and `e.target` as `#link2`, you may do something like that:

```
$('#link2').click(function() {
    var e = $._data($('#link1')[0], 'events');
    e.click[0].handler.apply(this, arguments);
});
```

... which is not very much compact, clear, flexible and reliable, so good old multi element selection will do the job without overcomplicating the things:

```
$('#link1, #link2').click(function() {
    $(this).css('color', '#f00');
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/uRgxe/

Answer (score 2):

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/MrZzV/

This isn't as simple as you might have expected, as there's no clear way to pass context to a click event, however you can use the jQuery.data

the code :

```
$('#link2').click(function(){
    jQuery.data( $('#link1')[0] , "caller", this );
    $('#link1').click();
    jQuery.data( $('#link1')[0] , "caller", false );
});


$('#link1').click(function(){

   if(jQuery.data( $('#link1')[0] , "caller") === false)
   {
       caller = this;  

   }
   else
   {
           var caller = jQuery.data( $('#link1')[0] , "caller");

   }
   console.log(caller);


});
```

as you'll see, the caller is indeed different depends who you click

update : minor fix to the code, udpated fiddle

Comment: why are you posting this although you know that the OP just wanted to trigger another element's event? Also, newer versions use ._data, that is why I asked for the jQuery version

Comment: In his comment he asked to post a solution that takes context into account. **if you guys want to share an answer that answers the question more precisely (taking context into consideration), that would be great** -- anyway I just showed a simple example of how to pass context, I was not aware of ._data, I'm no jquery expert. Many pardons :)

Comment: Thank you Patrick, it's appreciated. I will be sure to play around with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#link2').click(function(){
    $('#link1').click();
});
```

**[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/click/)**

Answer (score 0):

We can choose both links in selector

```
$("#link1,#link2").click(function()
{
      //write common code
});
```